# Error running ClickHouse Docker on MacBook M1

Tags: docker, clickhouse, apple-m1

I'm running ClickHouse Docker image on MacBook M1 and getting the following error.

```
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
    clickhouse-02_1  | fatal error: newosproc
    clickhouse-02_1  |
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime stack:
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.throw(0x4cb21f, 0x9)
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.newosproc(0xc420028000, 0xc420037fc0)
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:160 +0x194
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.newm(0x4d6db8, 0x0)
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1572 +0x132
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.main.func1()
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x36
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.systemstack(0x53ae00)
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x79
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.mstart()
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079
    clickhouse-02_1  |
    clickhouse-02_1  | goroutine 1 [running]:
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.systemstack_switch()
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0xc420022768 sp=0xc420022760
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.main()
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:127 +0x6c fp=0xc4200227c0 sp=0xc420022768
    clickhouse-02_1  | runtime.goexit()
    clickhouse-02_1  |  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1 fp=0xc4200227c8 sp=0xc4200227c0
    clickhouse-02_1  | Configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml' isn't readable by user with id '101'
```

I think this is because it is an amd64 image but I have other amd64 images like influxDB running smoothly with emulators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, Clickhouse is working for me in my M1 with the latest version Clickhouse v21.11

Using docker image : yandex/clickhouse-server

Comment: I have tried it,unfortunately the container keeps restarting on my m1 macos

Comment: clickhouse/clickhouse-server:22.6-alpine works for me on M1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `--platform linux/amd64` in the run command?

```
docker run -it -p 9000:9000 -p 9009:9009 -p 8123:8123 --platform linux/amd64 --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 clickhouse/clickhouse-server
```

Comment: I've seen the platform error before - your error looks different. Have you seen this conversation: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/18927

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, ended up using the alpine version which fixed the error for me